# Symfony2 XDebug stops on breakpoint and can't do anything with debug buttons

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug

I have installed XDebug for Symfony2.

I have edit php->php.ini with:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp
```

And apache->php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 10000
```

**My run configuration is:**
*Project URL:* `http://localhost/testing/web/app_dev.php`
*Debug URL:* `Ask Every Time`

**Path mapping:**
*Server path:* `C:/wamp/www/testing`
*Project path:* `C:\wamp\www\Testing\src\Acme\LogInSystemBundle`

My problem is when I start debugging, it stops on breakpoint and I can't do anything with debug buttons, even I can click on it. Therefore, how can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In wamp/bin/php/php_xxx/ I have a folder called "zend_ext". My php.ini there is a line:

zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"

Maybe you should check out this pageÉ
http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#How_to_configure_xdebug_with_WAMP

Comment: I did it, but result is same. I have used wamp server, NetBeans and I work on Windows 7. I really don't know what problem is... But, thank you!